# Glasses mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs, customization

How to customize the color of the symbol inserted in the "glasses mode" in Emacs?
I have not found the option for this. Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no option to set the face for the inserted separator (and from a brief study of the docs for emacs overlays, I don't think it's simple to add).

You can customize the face used for the capital letters that glasses-mode splits on; it's called `glasses-face`.

Answer (score 3):

You can reset `glasses-separator` either by hand or in your .emacs file to change the symbol. My elisp is rusty, but I think

```
(setq glasses-separator "~")
```

does that. At this point we have not changed the type face at all.

I think you may have to hack the mode (glasses.el) to accomplish this.

(defers to Allen's better reading of the question...)

Comment: Well, yeah, I use following lines for this:
 '(glasses-original-separator "")
 '(glasses-separator "·") 
in my custom vars section.
It helps to be sure that glasses are added by emacs and are not available in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to see the customisations available for `glasses-mode` is to enter:

```
M-x customize-group
```

and then enter `glasses` at the `Customize group (default emacs):` prompt.

However, you will need to set up a [custom.el file](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Customizations.html) first.